# Is moment of inertia numerically additive?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

---

**NOTE:** The following argument is being made for **square only**, not any general shape.

---

We have this square plate:

[image]

From **Perpendicular Axis theorem**,

$$I_1 + I_2 = I_z \\ I_3 + I_4 = I_z$$

Also, $$I_1 = I_2 \\ I_3 = I_4$$

Therefore, $$2\ I_1 = I_z \\ \text{and  }\ \ 2\ I_3 = I_z \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Then we get $$I_1 = I_2 = I_3 = I_4 \\ I_1 + I_3 = I_z$$

Although we get this to be true numerically, My instructor told me that last equation is wrong even for square. He said that it doesn't follow any known theorem. But I think this reason is somewhat unsatisfactory.

**Q** Are the last two results really correct (for square) (at tensor level) ?

Comment: It is only true because of the symmetry of the shape. For another shape it won't be true. That's why.

Comment: But my instructor said that it wont be true even for square. @ja72

Comment: I just see what you mean, and I am very surprised. I will have to think about it a little.

Comment: I agree with Ja72, is just a coincidence because of the symmetry, it is not a general theorem but it is true in this and other cases with similar symmetry. Your equation is wrong in general, but not in this particular case. You either misunderstood your instructor
 or he is wrong.

Comment: I know it is not a theorem! But he says it is not true for square too. Where in my post i said that it was assumed to be a general theorem? It mentions in the beginning that the shape is square. **And everything is being said for square plate only**.

Comment: Then you should ask your instructor for the actual moments of intertia. (It's a simple calculation.)

Comment: $I_1+I_2=I_z$ and $I_3=I_2$ imply $I_1+I_3=I_z$, so yeah, it's true. Nothing sophisticated going on here except that your professor is worried you might misapply the perpendicular axis theorem to the pair $I_1$ and $I_3$.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy thanks! but actually i think issue is something else with my prof. He said that if you compare their tensors, they will be different. Now there we haven't learnt anything about tensors, so i was a bit perplexed!

Comment: @Max Payne: Do you distinguish the properties of _being additive_ and _being numerically additive?_

Answer (score 2):

The equations you derived, especially the last two are true only for the square shape. Because it has inherent symmetries as mentioned by ja72 and others. But your instructor told you that those equations were not true for squares also. He probably did some mistake. The most probable case is the following:

We know that moment of inertia actually depends not only on mass but also on distribution of mass around the considered axis. Now in your picture, clearly, the mass distribution around I1 is till distance a on both sides(assuming the length of the square to be 2a). But for I3 the distribution is till 1.4a. So how is it that they have same Moment of Inertia.

The answer to it is actually pretty simple. It's because the mass distribution is different in the two cases. In case of I1, the mass is equally spread throughout the distance, whereas in I3, the mass is more closer to the axis but decreases linearly with distance. That's why the two M.I. turns out to be same.